# line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: build, amazon-dynamodb

```
- name: Add items to DynamoDB table
    run: |
      aws dynamodb put-item --table-name name-1 --item "{\"FeatureName\": {\"S\":\"Handler\"},\"Active\": {\"BOOL\": false }}"  --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
      aws dynamodb put-item --table-name name-2 --item "{\"FeatureName\": {\"S\":\"Launcher\"},\"Active\": {\"BOOL\": false }}" --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
      aws dynamodb put-item --table-name name-3 --item "{\"FeatureName\": {\"S\":\"Notification\"},\"Active\": {\"BOOL\": false }}"  --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

I have this in my build.yaml file and I'm not sure why I'm getting an error when I deploy this: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

I used single quotes before but got an error saying to use double quotes so I changed to double quotes.